# Generate different (click) attributes in a ngFor loop of buttons from array

Tags: angular, button, click, ngfor

I have a JSON file from which I get configuration to generate an array of buttons in a toolbar.

In each record, I store information about each button, as well as the class, the icon ... and I also want to set in each button the method that will trigger through the event `(click)`

How do I generate each button in the view with its click event?

It is an angular component that generates a toolbar based on the information it receives from this `JSON` file

I need something like:

HTML

```html
<mat-button-toggle-group>
    <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let tool of tools">
      <button [click]="tool.click"><i [class]="tool.class"></i></button>
    </mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Array (JSON file)

```json
tools =
  [
    { id: 0, class: 'fas fa-sign-out-alt', click: 'addPizza()'},
    { id: 1, class: 'fas fa-arrow-left', click: 'removePizza()' },
    { id: 2, class: 'far fa-sticky-note', click: 'updateGrid()' }
  ];
```

Expected: Generate a group of buttons within each button has a specific method

Comment: can you alter the json source? if not, it may get slightly more complex than expected. Other than that, `[click]` should be `(click)` instead.

Comment: I can alter the json source, but in which way do you mean to change it?

Comment: instead of having a string on the `click` key, I would recommend you to reference a method instead (or many method), so that the click binding would work as intended.

Comment: thank you a lot **Adrita Sharma** for your help, I did the stackblitz but it works so I didn´t share it with you. As I say in my answer, it seems that it doesn´t works if you generate the component information retrieving the data from a JSON by an Angular input... I found another way to solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved by another way,

Basically it was not working because i was retrieving the information by an input in the component, not by a direct variable within the component itself (I omitted this fact in my question).

So finally I created a method in the component that handle the function triggered depending on the string setted on the click property in the JSON file:

JSON:

```
tools =
  [
    { id: 0, class: 'fas fa-sign-out-alt', click: 'addPizza'},
    { id: 1, class: 'fas fa-arrow-left', click: 'removePizza' },
    { id: 2, class: 'far fa-sticky-note', click: 'updateGrid' }
  ];
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<button *ngFor="let tool of tools" (click)="handleClick(tool.click)">
  <i [class]="tool.class" ></i>
</button>
```

Component:

```
  handleClick(method: string) {
   switch (method) {
     case 'addPizza':
     this.addPizza();
    break;
     case 'removePizza':
     this.removePizza();
    break;
     case 'updateGrid':
     this.updateGrid();
    break;

  default:
    break;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Make two changes, In Template replace `[click]="tool.click"` with `(click)="tool.click()"` and in TS, make `click` property a **function**

Try like this:

TS:

```
tools =
  [
    { id: 0, class: 'fas fa-sign-out-alt', click: () => this.addPizza()},
    { id: 1, class: 'fas fa-arrow-left', click: () => this.removePizza() },
    { id: 2, class: 'far fa-sticky-note',click: () => this.updateGrid() }
  ];
```

Template:

```
 <button (click)="tool.click()"><i [class]="tool.class"></i></button>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(click)="tool.click()"`?

Comment: Yes.. I updated the answer. Thanks. Copied it from the question, forgot to add `()`

Comment: It is not working, when I click the button it throws: **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addPizza' of undefined**

Comment: Can you share a stackbiltz, it should work. The error means **this** is undefined, which shouldn't be. I think the issue is somewhere else